# Multiclient server in C - which method is the best for this particular situation?

Tags: c, multithreading, winsock

I need to write a server which is going to run under Windows XP or later. And I'm not sure about solution for it. Let me break it down:

Server stores a list of all connected clients - it receive packets when client wants to join or leave the server and it is also sending a list of all connected clients to every client every 5 seconds.

Now I don't know if I should use separate thread for every client on server?(Client ammount can be up to 50) or should I use 1 thread and use select with asychronous sockets?

Comment: You might be interested in this server here, which is open-source/BSD and does the things you want your server to do (via a single-threaded, non-blocking design):  https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/

Answer (score 1):

With few clients synchronous thread-based IO is usually the easiest (most productive) choice. With many clients you can save a ton of memory and scheduling overhead by using async IO.

With 50 clients you are on the verge between the two cases. I'd go synchronous and just reduce the stack size of my worker threads a bit. But even if you have to live with the default 1MB of stack space this approach is still viable.

The reason why synchronous is preferred is that async IO is hard to get right, a lot of work, error prone, harder to debug and it converts your code into a mess of callbacks. In exchange for that you don't block threads. Only go async if the memory savings are worth it.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, you need:

- A handful of clients (50)
- Few messages sent (connection status every 5s)
- Shared state (list of all clients to each)

This sounds like a clear case for *not* using threads. They'll cause synchronization headaches to handle that common state, and all the communication needs to go through the same network stack anyhow. You'll also want to avoid blocking communication, since one hung (or missing) client could prevent others from receiving updates. I would stick to non-blocking sockets using select (or equivalently, poll). The trickiest state you'll need to track is when you've sent a partial list to some client, keeping that version of the list around until it has been sent fully.

Note that non-blocking I/O should not be confused with the asynchronous I/O APIs. Those involve automated callbacks at unpredictable times (the userspace equivalent of hardware interrupts); with select, you choose when to check status and how to handle it. Multithreading can be used as a method to get asynchronous behaviour out of blocking I/O, but causes the same synchronization issues *and* requires more state to be tracked per thread (each has its own stack). Some environments (for instance node.js) make some particular of these techniques easier or even mandatory.

Select does fall out of favour when you pass a few hundred sockets, simply because it involves passing the lists back and forth (it may even have a limit on the list size). That issue is known as the C10K problem, for ten thousand connections; we're not anywhere close in this case. Similarly if you need to do much processing per client, multithreading is required to exploit multicore processors.

Comment: Thanks, I will stick to select and non blocking sockets then - wish me luck.